# NGROK IIS windows authenticate

Tags: iis, ngrok

I have simple Blazor app, that uses windows authentication. In the launch settings I have enabled both anonymous authentication and windows authentication (windows required by blazor)

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54819",
      "sslPort": 44398
    }
  },
```

When I run the app locally everything works just fine, however when I provision tunnel in ngrok via:

`ngrok http https://localhost:44398/ --host-header=localhost:44398`

I get login prompt when I visit the tunneled site, no matter what I include it always fails.

The response then looks as follows:

[image: img]